# How to reinitialize a terminal window instead of closing it and starting a new one?

Tags: bash

When I make some changes to the shell/bash behavior, such as setting up an alias, is there a quick command to reinitialize the terminal window instead of closing and opening a new window?

Answer (score 90, accepted):

If you mean reloading your .bashrc configuration then:

`source ~/.bashrc`

For less typing, you can replace `source` with a dot: `. ~/.bashrc`

Comment: Here is a question, how does this behave differently than `source ~/.bashrc` ?

Comment: It doesn't. Looking at the bash man page you will see that the commands are listed as equivalent.

Comment: `source` is a specific to bash.  `.` is more standard.  Both work the same in bash.

Comment: This just reloads your PATH and some environment variables. It doesn't "reset" anything. @NES's answer is the correct one.

Comment: This doesn't reset anything, if you had updates to your PATH you'll now have your old updates and new updates.

Comment: For anyone looking for an actual solution because this is not at all the same as closing and starting a new one. Everything that was exported to the env will still be there. The [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1129323/616464) of @isarandi is what you might be looking for.

Answer (score 65):

Some Addition i found in the manpage from the reset/tset command

tset reset terminal intialization

command: `reset`

Tset  initializes  terminals.   Tset  first  determines  the type of terminal that you are
using.  This determination is done as follows, using the first terminal type found.

an advantage seems to be, that it's independent from the used shell. also works with fish here.

So to reinitialize any terminal just do-

```
$ tset
```

OR

```
$ reset
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is also wrong. It does not reset existing environment variables.

Comment: I think the full answer would be `tput reset && source ~/.profile`.

Comment: Nice! It worked for me!

Answer (score 13):

An additional option to the `exec bash` is that if you changed your `.profile` (or `.bash_profile`), you can do

```
$ exec bash --login
```

That will read your profile again as well.  It wouldn't hurt to add the `-i` option as well to explicitly tell bash that this is an interactive shell, but it can normally figure that out for itself.

Comment: for me it works without exec too

Comment: Unfortunately wrong as well. Already set environment variables are still there and aren't reset.

Comment: @ArmenSanoyan but that would create a new chile process, with the shell calling `bash --login` as its parent. Using `exec bash --login` will replace the current shell, as explained in [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html)

Comment: @isarandi I've found that using `exec -c bash --login`, the command will be executed with an empty environment. But it seems that some important env vars are not reinitialized, which makes my `~/.bashrc` not executed. I think the problem lies in how the initial env vars passed to the `~/.profile` script

Comment: @ArmenSanoyan: Without `exec`, the original `bash` stays running as the parent of this process, and hitting control-D in the new shell will exit back to that shell.

Comment: @PeterCordes Sure, but are there any practical drawbacks to that? For all intents and purposes, we are in a "new shell", even if it is running in the old one

Comment: @information_interchange: the old `bash` is still sitting around in the process list (and waste a few MiB of RAM, which is trivial these days on desktops).  And when you eventually `exit` (or control-d) out of that shell much later, the terminal window / tab won't close and you'll be wondering if it didn't work.

Comment: `exec -c bash --login` gets me in a weird colorless shell that for some reason also explains me how the sudo command works. Sourcing .profile or .bashrc does nothing afterwards.

Answer (score 12):

Use `exec sudo --login --user $USER`.

If you also want the previously entered commands to disapper (full reset of the terminal), combine it with `reset` as `reset; exec sudo --login --user $USER`.

To keep the current working directory as well, use the following function:

```bsh
reinit(){
  reset
  exec sudo --login --user "$USER" /bin/sh -c "cd '$PWD'; exec '$SHELL' -l"
}
```

There are many answers around the web but most don't actually work. Easy way to test is to set `export SOMEVAR=42` then execute the supposedly resetting command and do `echo $SOMEVAR`. If it's 42, the environment was not reset.

There is also `exec -c bash -l` or `exec env -i bash -l`, but these are broken, somehow the $HOME variable is not set after this.

Comment: To keep the current directory as well: `exec sudo --login --user $USER sh -c 'cd '"$PWD"'; bash'`

Comment: Thanks, that's useful. See my edit, which does not assume bash and uses -l to ensure a login shell and uses exec so there are no nested shells.

Comment: best answer! Strangely though the PATH is not exactly the same as from a fresh terminal...

Answer (score 10):

You have to **replace** the running application/shell with a new instance. E.g. if you are using `bash` as your preferred shell type the following line in your command line (*$* is the placeholder for the beginning of your command line):

```
> $ exec bash
```

The running application/shell is replaced by new instance of `bash` like starting from scratch. All your previous modification are gone.

*Remark: Do not forget that your terminal application may be reprogrammed. You have to reset your terminal application manually.*

Comment: What do you mean by "reprogrammed"?

Comment: This answer is also wrong. exec inherits the environment from its predecessor. Hence it does not restore environment variables. Some may be reloaded by running a new bash but those that are not overwritten are not removed.

Answer (score 0):

your shell is an executable you can call. So if you're using bash you can call `bash` and if you're using something else like zsh you can just enter `zsh`

Comment: This was my thought as well, but I am worried that there will be some issues

Comment: this will create another zsh session in an already existing one which is not happening in case of `exec zsh`

Answer (score 0):

Use the terminal's functions [clear](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/clear.1.html) or [screen](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/screen.1.html).

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu at least, `. ~/.profile` is better than `. ~/.bashrc`, because the .profile file also sources the .bashrc file, *and* it brings in other dirs, such as `~/bin` to your PATH if those dirs exist.